# Join column to a new dataframe, but only when customerID exists

Tags: pyspark

I want to give test a new column, named customerCategory. If the new customer is already in test, I want to give him the same value as in train. Otherwise I want to fill the column with `WHITE`.

What I have already tried (Throws an error):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
test = test.withColumn("customerCategory", 
F.when(F.col("customerID")!=train["customerID"], "WHITE")\
.otherwise(train["customerCategory"]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is more a Join and Coalesce requirement in sql terms. An example would be like below.

```
test=test.join(train,test.customerID ==  train.customerID,"left_outer").drop(train.customerID)
test= test.withColumn('customerCategory', F.coalesce(F.col("customerCategory"),F.lit("WHITE")))
```